# Traduction du terme « Golden Hour » utilisé par les photographes

Tags: vocabulaire, jargon, art

En anglais, « *Golden Hour* » désigne les périodes après le lever du soleil et avant son coucher où la lumière est plus douce.

Quelle est l'expression équivalente en français ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En France, les photographes utilisent les expressions suivantes :

> - l'heure magique
> - le moment magique
> - le quart d’heure magique
> - le quart d’heure de vérité

Un article faisant référence à ces termes: [Les 15 minutes magiques en photographie de paysages](http://www.guillenphoto.com/cms/les-15-minutes-magiques-en-photographie-de-paysages.html)

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 0):

En français aussi le plus courant est simplement de garder golden hour

Comment: @Begueradj Non, c'est bien une réponse. Je ne suis pas sûre qu'elle soit correcte, par contre, mais je ne suis pas photographe. En regardant un peu sur Google Books, j'ai l'impression que [heure magique](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22l%27heure%20magique%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) est plus répandue que [golden hour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22golden%20hour%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) quand il s'agit de la lumière solaire.

Comment: Peut-être, mais il n'a pas étayé sa réponse par une documentation, pour moi c'est louche surtout que c'est de l'anglicisme, ce qui fait de sa contribution un commentaire et non pas une réponse fiable. Mais puisque vous êtes plus expérimenté, peut-être vous avez raison, à vous de décider. @Gilles